# Phonegap splash screen image distorted

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, splash-screen

Splash screen didint show up and I found that I was missing the default splash screen in confix.xml

I updated my config with splash.png but when I open the app the splash screen looks distorted.

Does somebody can explain why, and what size should I use to look normal?

I test on a Samsung Galaxy S2

```
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently was just cache.

Remove app, reinstall and works as a charm.